# iPad Popover containing an UIWebView will not dismiss if ever touched inside webview

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIWebView inside a popover.

As long as I never tap (scroll, etc) the webview all is fine.  That is, if I tap anywhere on the screen outside of the popover the popover is dismissed.

However, if I tap (scroll, etc) inside the webview, then tapping outside of the popover fails to dismiss the popover.

Answer (score 1):

this was fixed by the gold master of 4.3